# Combining jQuery filtering and Bootstrap rows

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple bootstrap grid like this

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="parent">
            <div class="row row-striped">
                <div class="category1 col-xs-12">
                    //of course more cols and contents in them
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

and I put a filter on it by buttons with IDs (thanks to https://codepen.io/terf/post/jquery-filter-divs)

```
    <button class="btn btn-link" id="category1">Category 1</button>
```

but because i need a background on every second row, I decided to add a new row with jQuery every 2 items. This causes a problem to my filter, because whenever I filter, the new row is being kept (and empty).

This is the Javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alignDivs() {
        var $mainElem = $('.row.row-striped'),
                $parent = $mainElem.parent(), // div#parent
                $items = $mainElem.children(':gt(1)').detach(); // detach all +1 items

        if ($items.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $items.length; i = i + 2) { // 2 items per row
                var $row = $('<div class="row row-striped">').append($items.slice(i, i + 2));
                // new row with previously detached items
                $parent.append($row);
            }
        }
    }

    alignDivs(); //initially align cols/rows

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $btns = $('.btn').click(function () {
            if (this.id === 'all') {
                $('#parent').find('> .row > div').fadeIn(450);
                alignDivs(); //reload col/row layout
            } else {
                var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
                $('#parent').find('> .row > div').not($el).hide();
                alignDivs(); //reload col/row layout
            }
            $btns.removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');

        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried stuff like .on('change'), or removing the before-last row (.eq(-2)) but it doesn't work as I expect it to. When i remove the before-last row for example, it still deletes the one with my item inside instead of the empty one.

**What I want is to have 2 items in a row and then open a new one, and if only 2 items exist after the filter, delete the new row between them so its one row with 2 items again - and not 1 item per row.**

Here is a jsFiddle with my current code, where you can see the problem if you click on Website or Online-Shop:
https://jsfiddle.net/a3e7xmho/1/

Comment: If you just delete the alignDivs function it works like you want, if I have understood you correctly.

Comment: Sadly it does not, because i would lose the blue background on every second row then (alignDivs was made to add that new row every 2 items), otherwise it would.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.

The trick is to set the background dynamically with jQuery to the cols themselves instead of the row and check for the :visible-state.

```
function setBackgroundPositions() {
        var width = $('.row-striped').width();
        $('.col-project:visible').each(function(i) {
            if (i % 4 >= 2) {
                $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
            } else {
                $(this)
                        .css('background-image', 'url("/img/projects/image.png")')
                        .css('background-position', ((i % 4) * -1 * (width/2)) + "px 0")
                        .css('background-size', 'cover');
            }
        });
    }
```